# Solving systems of modular linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am looking for references for solving systems of linear equations $Ax = b \bmod m$, i.e., $Ax=b$ where all entries are in the ring ${\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z}$.

I know that when $m$ is prime then we have a field and so standard linear algebra applies. I know also that we can use the Chinese remainder theorem to reduce to the case where $m$ is a prime power. That's where I am stuck.

I am hoping there is some canonical textbook (or perhaps a chapter in an algebra or linear algebra textbook) that covers this material comprehensively, e.g., defining appropriate notions of linear independence, rank, bases, etc. that are applicable to this case.

I know also that this problem is connected more generally to module theory and/or general linear equations over commutative rings. If you are aware of an introductory-level treatment of that material that would help here, that is also ok. But I would actually prefer *not* to get bogged down in a general treatment if I can avoid it, because all I care about  is the modular case.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! If you reduceto the prime power case, the problem is linked to [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma), which is the basis for the construction of $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: The treatment of Hensel's lemma on Wikipedia, at least, only discusses the case of univariate polynomials. In contrast, I am looking at systems of equations and only care about the linear case.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664536/systems-of-linear-equations-over-integers-modulo-n).

Comment: Thank you for the link to the other post. I was hoping for a more comprehensive reference (if one exists). Plus, the answer there was not completely satisfying (until I edited it).

Comment: By the adjoint formula, a necessary condition for the existence of a solution is that $gcd(detA,m)$ divides $(AdjA\cdot b)_i$ for each component of $AdjA\cdot b$.