# Counting solutions to modular linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, matrix-equations

I am posting this as a followup to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877214/solving-systems-of-modular-linear-equations) in the hopes that a more specific question might elicit an answer.

Let $p$ be prime and $n>1$ an integer, and consider the system of equations 
$\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right] \cdot \left[ \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right] = {\bf 0} \bmod p^n$ in the unknowns $x, y$ (i.e., $a, b, c, d$ are given).

How can we determine how many nonzero solutions there are to this system of equations?

(Obviously if $n=1$ then this is all easy; I am surprised(?) that the more general case seems to be barely discussed.)

Comment: That is true, but I don't think it solves the problem completely.

Comment: HINT.-Put $a-c=m$ and $b-d=n$ so you have the necessary condition $mx+ny=0\mod p^n$. Similarly with $a+c$ and $b+d$ Can this be useful? I think yes.

Comment: I'm looking for something less ad hoc. For example, when $n=1$ we can characterize things exactly: let $r$ be the rank of the matrix; the number of solutions is $p^{2-r}$. I am looking for some similar characterization (which would require the right definition of "rank," for starters) here.

Comment: I did find the paper "Fast Algorithms for Linear Algebra Modulo N" by Storjohann and Mulders, https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~astorjoh/esa.pdf

Comment: For what it's worth, although the given reference shows how to compute a normal-form representation for the set of solutions to the equation, I still don't see how to use it to count the number of solutions in a computationally tractable way.